# What is the difference between Build Solution and Batch Build in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, build

What is the difference between Build Solution and Batch Build in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The key point which seems to be missed in both the existing answers is that batch build allows you to build *multiple configurations* of each project (e.g. you can build debug *and* release configurations with a single operation).

With a normal build, you have to use the configuration manager to select just one configuration for each project.

Comment: also, if you have builds for different languages/conditions, batch build lets you build all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what has been mentioned so far, batch build allows a combination of projects or configurations to be stored as a *preset* for easier future access.

Answer (score 0):

Batch build allows you to build any project that you select, and a Solution build only builds the projects that are part of the active solution.

You can customise what projects are part of a solution build by going to menu *Tools* → *Configuration Manager*.

Comment: For anyone with VS 2013, it looks like it's under "BUILD->Configuration Manager..." now.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice thing about batch build is that it lets you build a configuration different than the current one. It is handy for solutions that take a while to switch.

Answer (score -3):

Building the solution is the same as batch building all projects.  Both methods respect the solution's dependencies.